# Intra Pair Length Mismatch Tolerance For 12.5Gbps signals

Tags: fpga, differential, high-speed, transceiver, length-matching

I'm making a high-speed transceiver design and want some direction regarding layout of trace length from P to N. The speeds will be up to 12.5Gbps. I have been informed by a equalizer manufacturer that up to 1mm intrapair skew (P-N length mismatch) is hard to measure, and will have no effect on signals up to 12.5Gbps.
Do you guys agree to this? If you do length match to a closer intrapair length, then what guides do you end up following for your serpentines?
Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Chance

Comment: How much time difference does the receiver allow?

Comment: Hello @Justme, I'm not sure where to get this information. My question is broad, and is in respect to multiple standards in the design. I have an equalizer with the above statement from the manufacturer, stating that 1mm intrapair skew is not noticeable at 12.5Gbps speed, however, when looking at another signal standard operating at 2.5Gbps, I am recommended to have a 0.0127mm intrapair skew. Essentially, I'm trying to find the answer to the question -> If a 12.5Gbps diff pair can handle up to 1mm intra pair skew, then shouldn't all signals <= 12.5Gbps be able to handle the same P/N skew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Golden rule analysis**

12.5 Gbps at full rate 101010101... style data has a fundamental frequency of 6.25 GHz and, it also has harmonics of 3x, 5x, 7x etc.. So, depending on how good your receiver is you may need to take into account the 7th harmonic (43.75 GHz).

Now, 43.75 GHz has a free-space wavelength of 6.85 mm but, it's probably going to be about two-thirds of that when travelling along a transmission-line so, it's more like 5mm.

The golden rule used in electronics is that you begin to have small problems when length mismatches are about one-tenth of the effective wavelength of the highest frequency of signal that you are interested in.

That means I'd be looking (broadly speaking) to match lengths to within 0.5 mm.

If your receiver has a more limited bandwidth and only requires the 5th harmonic (31.25 GHz) to be fairly accurately representative then the shortest wavelength of interest will be two-thirds of 9.6 mm (6.4 mm). Hence, in these circumstances I'd be looking to match to within 0.64 mm.

Clearly you can take this analysis down to the third harmonic where you'd find that you'd need to match to within 1.25 mm but, that's where you have to stop because you run out of bandwidth for a signal that is 101010101... in nature.

Comment: To illucidate further again, do you happen to know how to measure wiggly tracks - it strikes me that the signal won’t necessarily take the shortest path or the midline of the track, so intuitively a very wiggly track might ‘blur’ signal timing since it’s length isn’t well-defined.  Or is it inappropriate to think in those terms at these high frequencies?  I’m happy to post this as a separate question but it seems very closely related to the OP

Comment: @Frog I think that this certainly merits a new question because, I don't think it's all that simply explained if you look into the details. I believe wiggly tracks do blur the signal a tad (more or less) because they present some weird changes in localized characteristic impedance. I've never had to look into this so I'd be reading any answers given. It is related to this question but it's also several steps in complication beyond it too.

Comment: Hello @Andyaka, do you have any suggestions on books to read for this information and the harmonics you would get at a certain frequency? Is this a rule of thumb how you got this info? Also, even though you state that the lengths could be matched within 0.5mm, would you match it closer? My big confusion was with the manufacturer stating that serpentines would cause more issues, and up to a 1mm gap intrapair would be better than adding a serpentine to length match the P/N traces.

Comment: It is probably slightly worse than you calculate. The signal velocity for a trace on a PCB is approximately c/sqrt(dielectric constant).  Since the permittivity is ~4 that gives  about 1/2 speed of light not 2/3. More exotic materials can be a bit better.

Comment: @KevinWhite yes you are quite correct.

Comment: @ChanceK I can't recommend books because I don't use books anymore. But for harmonics, just google the harmonics of a square wave i.e. 101010101 continuous changing data. The one-tenth wavelength thing is a rule of thumb and is widely quoted by many. I wouldn't worry anymore if lengths were matched to within one-twentieth of the wavelength.

Comment: Andy: For high frequency signals, yes. However, for something like a 25MHz differential clock you must definitely match much closer than to within one 20th the wavelength. Otherwise you get a "step" in the rising edge of your clock, and that would be quite bad. In reality there is hardly ever a reason to NOT match differential pairs to within 0.2mm regardless of the frequency. Only advantages and no drawback.

Comment: @TimmyBrolin yes for moderate speed clocks that rely on good edges and where the receiver circuit has a massive bandwidth that might extend to hundreds of MHz, you need to consider the highest important frequency and, that might be hundreds of MHz (even for a 25 MHz clock). Hence why I said `So, depending on how good your receiver is` at the top of my answer.